# SQL - Move last 2 character to become first 2

Tags: sql-server

I need move last 2 characters of string to become first 2, for example, "ABC PT" become "PT ABC".
Thanks for help.

Comment: And where exactly is your problem?

Comment: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: Did you try something? Have you checked the T-SQL [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), eg SUBSTRING and CONCAT ?

Comment: Seems to me that you want more than just moving the 2 last characters. Care to rephrase the question

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC PT'

SELECT RIGHT(@String, 2) + ' ' + LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) -2)

RESULT : PT ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` function.
for example :

```
select substring('ABC PT',len('ABC PT')-1,2)+' '+stuff('ABC PT',len('ABC PT')-1,2,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
DECLARE @Str as nvarchar(10);
SET @Str =  'ABC PT';
SELECT RTRIM(RIGHT(@Str,2)+' '+SUBSTRING(@Str, 1 , LEN(@Str)-2))
```

Result:

```
PT ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the select statement, use it to update if you want to
c1 is the column name in the table test15.
If you have a variable then replace c1 with the variable name and remove the from clause.

```
select RIGHT(c1,2)+SUBSTRING(c1,1,len(c1)-2) from test15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
  NAME VARCHAR(50)
 )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('PC1AB')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('PC2XY')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('PC3NA')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('PC3NAXBBNTEYE12')

SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME,LEN(NAME)-1,2)+LTRIM(LEFT(NAME,LEN(NAME)-2)) FROM #TEMP
```